# Lifetime risk and global annual rates

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm trying to understand the connection between lifetime risk and global annual rates.

As a simple example, imagine that there is a 10% lifetime risk of some genuinely random event (so we can ignore demographic factors and so on). Suppose there is a 10% lifetime risk of your nose falling off.

Based on that, and making a few assumptions about average life expectancy (let's say 80 years, though I know it's closer to 75) and global population (let's say 8 billion, and we can keep it fixed for simplicity), how many annual nose losses could we expect?

My simple approach was to say 10% of 8 billion is 800 million events, spread out over 80 years, for 10 million annual events, but this seems way too simple a way to ballpark it.

Any suggestions or thoughts? Does this simple way hold water? (And if I'm in the wrong place for this one, please point me in the right direction.)

Edited in response to answers: my original choice of a UFO sighting was a bad one, because I didn't think about single events being witnessed by multiple people. My intention was to imagine a single event experienced individually, hence the change to noses falling off.

Comment: Are the events "person $i$ see an UFO" and "person $j$ see an UFO" independent? I would say no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the annual per-person probability of the event, and $p_L$ be the lifetime per-person probability.  Then assuming that each person has the same fixed total lifespan of $\omega$ years, and that the risk each year is independent of any previous year, the relationship between $p$ and $p_L$ is $$(1-p)^\omega = 1 - p_L.$$  This is because the lifetime probability of not having the event must equal the probability of no event in each year of life.  Thus $$p = 1 - (1 - p_L)^{1/\omega}.$$

Then the expected number of annual events in a population of size $N$ would simply be $$Np = N(1 - (1 - p_L)^{1/\omega}),$$ which for $N = 8 \times 10^9$, $p_L = 0.1$, and $\omega = 75$, yields $1.123 \times 10^7$ events per year.

In practice, this value makes assumptions that are perhaps unrealistic, such as a fixed total lifespan and a fixed total population.  Another assumption not stated but implied is that the event is not life-threatening; i.e., the probability of experiencing the event has no relationship to lifespan.  But without additional parameters and assumptions, it is not feasible to construct a more sophisticated model.

Comment: Thank you - I have to spend some time parsing this, but it looks good!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems to assume that UFO sightings are independent events, among people.  For example, if Mars attacks New York, you will have a great many people simultaneously sighting a UFO.

Further, if you assume that all UFO sights are a delusion, then one has to wonder whether delusions are independent events among people.  So, it depends on what you intend by the phrase *random event*.  If you intend that UFO sightings among people are independent events, then it seems like your approach is okay.

Alternatively, if you don't intend such independence, then it is not that great a stretch to presume that UFO sightings may be shared delusions by people in a common neighborhood (or shared Internet gossip, or whatever).

In fact, the $10$ million distinct annual UFO sightings seems way too high, although I could be mistaken.  The idea is that there are fewer annual sightings (delusional or otherwise), but when the sighting event does occur, it is typically shared by a large number of people.

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful - yes, I did intend independent events. (and annual UFO sightings are a bad example, I now realize based on your answer, as per my edit ...)